# Empty output while performing level order traversal in Binary trees in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, tree, breadth-first-search

I wanted to perform level order traversal in Binary Trees in Java. Basically I needed to store values of nodes of each level in an array list and store such different array lists in one single array list. In my final output, only empty array lists are being shown. I can not understand the logical error. Can anyone please guide me.

```
public class Solution {
        static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ourList=new ArrayList<>();
        static ArrayList<Integer>ourArray=new ArrayList<>();
        public static void breadth(Node root){
            Queue<Node> ourQueue=new LinkedList<>();
            ourQueue.add(root);
            while(!ourQueue.isEmpty()){
                int size=ourQueue.size();
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                    Node poppedElement=ourQueue.poll();
                    ourArray.add(poppedElement.data);
                    if(poppedElement.left!=null){
                        ourQueue.add(poppedElement.left);
                    }
                    if(poppedElement.right!=null){
                        ourQueue.add(poppedElement.right);
                    }
                }
                ourList.add(ourArray);
                ourArray.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following short test:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ourList=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer>ourArray=new ArrayList<>();
    //add values
    ourArray.add(1);  ourArray.add(2);  ourArray.add(3);  ourArray.add(4);
    ourList.add(ourArray);

    System.out.println(ourList.get(0)); //prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ourArray.clear();
    System.out.println(ourList.get(0)); //prints []
```

The reason is that `ourList` contains a reference to a list. `ourArray` is a reference to the same list, and when it is cleared, `ourList` contains a reference to an empty list.

Now test the solution proposed by [PHolzwarth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70814502/3992939):

```
    System.out.println(ourList.get(0)); //prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ourArray = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(ourList.get(0)); //prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

An alternative solution is a "defensive copy":

```
    ourList.add(new ArrayList<>(ourArray)); //add a copy of ourArray

    System.out.println(ourList.get(0)); //prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ourArray.clear();
    System.out.println(ourList.get(0)); //prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to collect the results in `ourList`, you need to create dedicated instances of the lists kept in `ourArray`. So, instead of clearing `ourArray`, you should probably re-create it: Instead of

```
ourArray.clear();
```

write

```
ourArray= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I got your point but why do I need to create dedicated instances using the 'new' keyword ? Can't I normally add array lists into an ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> data structure.

Comment: If you don't re-create it, it's the same list each time, so all entries in `ourList` point to the same list. And, as you clear that list with every while loop iteration, you keep discarding its contents.